# compress string into a2b3... etc

Tags: java, string

Just brushing up on some old java techniques. Currently working through a set of problems, and the one im on is compress strings in the format of aabbcccDDDDeff to a2b2c3d4e1f2. Something funky is happening in my code, pls help sort it out:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String c = "aabbCCCCCdfff";
    System.out.println(compress(c));
}

public static String compress(String s) {
    String ns = "";
    int count = 0;
    char temp = 0;

    for (int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++) {
        if (x == 0) {
            ns.concat(String.valueOf(s.charAt(x)));     
            temp = s.charAt(x);
            count++;
        } else if (temp == s.charAt(x)) {
            count++;
        } else {
            ns.concat(String.valueOf(count));
            count = 0;
            ns.concat(String.valueOf(s.charAt(x)));
            temp = s.charAt(x);
        }
    }
    return ns;
}
```

the output is just appearing as null. i'd like to keep my same logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.concat` ([String#concat docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#concat(java.lang.String))) doesn't mutate your string, it returns a new string that you need to assign to your string variable

```
ns = ns.concat(theOtherString);
```

and not this (which is essentially a no-op)

```
ns.concat(theOtherString);
```

for example:

```
ns = ns.concat(String.valueOf(s.charAt(x)));
```

I would recommend using `StringBuilder` with its `append` method for multiple string concatenations. If you choose not to then that is fine if you can argue why the performance benefit doesn't exist, or exists but doesn't apply, in your use case.

Comment: perfect. haha. Thanks alot andy! code is still messed up a bit but that is what i needed

Answer (score 0):

`String`s in Java are immutable. [`String.concat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) does not change the `String` it's called on, it returns a new `String` which is the concatination of the object it's called on and the parameter. If you want to accumulate strings, you'd be better served to use a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder ns = new StringBuilder();
int count = 0;
char temp = 0;

for (int x = 0; x < s.length(); x++) {
    if (x == 0) {
        ns.append(s.charAt(x));     
        temp = s.charAt(x);
        count++;
    // rest of code...
```